# How do you find Sean Parent's "Shoe laces and beans" data structure instead of tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I just watched Sean Parent's CppCon 2015 talk "[Better Code: Data Structures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWgDk-o-6ZE)", where he suggested a "Shoe laces and beans"
data structure instead of tree.

[image]

How do you find it? Do you think this is better than tree? what would be its strength what's price?

Comment: What do mean by better? More efficient, lesser memory usage or easier to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better is always depending on what you measure.
Here some possibilities for quality metrics:

- memory usage
- random access speed
- traversal speed
- ...

You can also look at worst case behavior or average case behavior.

So 'better' depends a lot on for what you will use it under which environment conditions / restrictions.

At least it has better cache-miss (and cache prefetch) characteristic while traversing it than a usual tree structure. That's because the elements are in order of traversal in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

The shoelace is easy to produce, as it correspond to a left recursive descent of the corresponding tree. So starting from a tree, you just have to descent it once and build the lace dynamically. After that, you doesn't need recursion anymore as the lace is simply a linked list of elements ordered as in the left recursive descent.

*Better than tree* ? It depends on what you want to do.